# multiple writes on fifo files

Tags: unix, client-server, ipc, named-pipes

How does a FIFO file(named pipe) handle multiple writes in UNIX.
 I read something about interleaving between writes but didn't catch it.
 Can you explain how exactly UNIX handles multiple writers and a single reader.

p.s. A classic example for this would be client-server communication.

The man page on fifo doesn't contain information about multiple writes. And also i didn't find anything interesting in google and in this website as well.

My exact question is "When there are multiple files writing into a fifo file, how does the reader differentiate between any of the writers?"

Comment: Did you do any research on that? What is your question actually? It is not documentation authors site, you know.. "man 1 mkfifo" would be a good start..

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/4/fifo The man page on fifo. This doesn't contain information about multiple writes. And also i didn't find anything interesting in google and in this website as well. My exact question is "When there are multiple files writing into a fifo file, how does the reader differentiate between any of the writers?"